# macOS で gulp の環境構築時に .bashrc が見つからない

Tags: macos, bash, gulp, zsh

gulpを使用した環境構築をしています。

> ```
> $ touch .bash_profile
> $ touch .bashrc
> ```

homeフォルダ内で `.bash_profile` のファイルは見つかりますが、
`.bashrc` のファイルが見つかりません。

コマンドを使わず作成可能でしょうか。
OSは最新のmac OS Montereyになります。

Answer (score 1):

> homeフォルダ内で `.bash_profile` のファイルは見つかりますが、
> `.bashrc` のファイルが見つかりません。

その前に、最近のMacOSのターミナルでのデフォルトシェルはzshです。
環境変数SHELLの内容を確認してください。

```
~ $ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

zshの場合、環境設定ファイルは、.zprofile、および、.zshrcになります。